# Unexpected result of win32 API InterlockedIncrement in multithread programming

Tags: multithreading, winapi, synchronization, thread-synchronization

```
 #include<string>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<process.h>
 #include<windows.h>
 using namespace std;

volatile int g_cnt = 0;

unsigned __stdcall threadFun(void *param)
{
    InterlockedIncrement((LONG volatile *)&g_cnt);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    const int threadNum = 1000;
    HANDLE hth[threadNum];

    for(int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++)
        hth[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, threadFun, NULL, 0, NULL);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(threadNum, hth, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for(int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++)
        CloseHandle(hth[i]);

    cout<<"the value of g_cnt: "<<g_cnt<<endl;
}
```

The function `InterlockedIncrement` ensure the operation of `g_cnt++` is atomic operation.  The final value of `g_cnt` should be 1000, but sometimes it is less than 1000, why?

**Note**:As @manuell said, `WaitForMultipleObjects` wait for `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` objects at most. `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS = 64` on my machine. So `WaitForMultipleObjects(threadNum, hth, TRUE, INFINITE);` should be replaced by:

```
        int k = threadNum / MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS;
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            WaitForMultipleObjects(MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS,
                                   &hth[i*MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS],
                                   TRUE, INFINITE);
        if(threadNum % MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS != 0)
            WaitForMultipleObjects(threadNum % MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS,
                                   &hth[k*MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS],
                                   TRUE, INFINITE);
```

Test environment: win7 X64 , codeblocks with gcc4.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your code doesn't works as expected. **Test the error conditions**.

For one, you can't wait on 1000 handles in a single call to `WaitForMultipleObjects`, so the call fails, so you don't know how many threads are still running when you read g_cnt.

On my current environment, `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` is 64.